Proof verification : $1+p\in (\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)^\times$ and its order is $p^{n-1}$
I want to show that $1+p$ is an element of $(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)^\times$ and its order is $p^{n-1}$ for odd prime $p$. (Dummit/Foote 2.3.21)
The textbook said one can prove it by using the Binomial Theorem to check:

$(1+p)^{p^{n-1}}\equiv 1 \text{(mod $p^n$)}$ 
$(1+p)^{p^{n-2}} \not\equiv 1\text{(mod $p^{n}$)}$

The calculation seemed good for me, but I didn't used the assumption that $p$ is an odd prime. So probably something gone wrong?
\begin{align*}
    (1+p)^{p^{n-1}}&=1+\binom{p^{n-1}}{1}\cdot p + \binom{p^{n-1}}{2}\cdot p^2+ \dots + \binom{p^{n-1}}{p^{n-1}}\cdot p^{p^n-1}\\
    &=1+ p^n + \frac{p^{n-1}(p^{n-1}-1)}{2!}\cdot p^2+\frac{p^{n-1}(p^{n-1}-1)(p^{n-1}-2)}{3!}\cdot p^3+\dots+p^{p^{n-1}}\\
    &=1+ p^n\left(1+\frac {p(p^{n-1}-1)}{2!}+\frac {p^2(p^{n-1}-1)(p^{n-1}-2)}{3!}+\dots+p^{p^{n-1}-n}\right)\\
    &\equiv 1 \text{ (mod $p^n$)}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    (1+p)^{p^{n-2}}&=1+\binom{p^{n-2}}{1}\cdot p + \binom{p^{n-2}}{2}\cdot p^2+ \dots + \binom{p^{n-2}}{p^{n-2}}\cdot p^{p^{n-2}}\\
    &=1+ p^{n-1}+\frac{p^{n-2}(p^{n-2}-1)}{2!}\cdot p^2+
    \frac{p^{n-2}(p^{n-2}-1)(p^{n-2}-3)}{3!}\cdot p^3+\dots+p^{p^{n-2}}\\
    &\equiv 1+p^{n-1} \text{ (mod $p^n$)}
\end{align*}

You’re secretly using the fact that, for all $0<k<p^{n-1}$, $$p^{n} \biggl | \binom{p^{n-1}}{k}p^k $$ in the first calculation, and, for $1<k<p^{n-2}$, $$p^{n} \biggl | \binom{p^{n-2}}{k}p^k,$$
in the second calculation. Both are not clearly true in general and require careful arguments. In fact, the second statement is false of you take $p$ non-prime e.g. take $n=3, k=2, p=4$ and check that
$$64 \not \biggl | 16\binom{4}{2}, $$ since $$4\not \biggl| \binom{4}{2}.$$ I imagine the first one is false too if you drop this assumption, but I’m on my phone so I didn’t look too hard.
